# Get YouTube videoId when thumbnail is clicked with YouTube Data API

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube-data-api

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/6b6a347c7d24edee15b3491420db4ecd?editors=011

So, I have this demo that has the basic search functions working... But what I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the thumbnail of the video, it will return the videoId (ex. BFjgsvM2gZ0 [The code after the youtube.com/?watch=**BFjgsvM2gZ0**]).

I don't want to achieve this using any  tags, just pure jQuery by the way!

**jQuery:**

```
     var apikey = 'AIzaSyDYwPzLevXauI-kTSVXTLroLyHEONuF9Rw';

        $(function() {
            var searchField = $('#search-input');

            $('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        function search() {
            $('#results').html('');

            q = $('#search-input').val();

            $.get(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
                    part: 'snippet, id',
                    q: q,
                    maxResults: 50,
                    type: 'video',
                    key: apikey
                },
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                        var output = getResults(item);

                        $('#results').append(output);
                    });
                });
        }

        function getResults(item) {
            var videoID = item.id.videoId;


        var title = item.snippet.title;
        var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
        var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;

        var output = '<li>' +
            '<div class="list-left">' +
            '<img src="' + thumb + '">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="list-right">' +
            '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' +
            '<p class="cTitle">' + channelTitle + '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</li>' +
            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
            '';

        return output;

}
```

As always thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a videoID, you can add new variable in getResults:

```
var videoID = item.id.videoId;
```

And then paste this in your output.

Sample 1: Alert videoID: http://jsfiddle.net/DmitriyBorisov/jf8402qk/

Sample 2: Open YouTube Video in blank window: http://jsfiddle.net/DmitriyBorisov/jf8402qk/1/